# Update sql record with ADO.Net by using a button

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

I'm trying to update a sql table by using ADO.Net. I can insert records without any problems, but I can't find a way to update the records there.

I have this code with the update method, it's inside the class **Person**

```
public bool UpdatePerson()
        {
            Database db = new Database();

            SqlConnection cn = db.OpenConnection();
            SqlTransaction tran = cn.BeginTransaction();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.Transaction = tran;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "update person set name = @name, " +
                "age = @age, sex = @sex where id = @id";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sex", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = Name;
            cmd.Parameters[1].Value = Age;
            cmd.Parameters[2].Value = Sex;
            cmd.Parameters[3].Value = Id;

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                tran.Commit();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                tran.Rollback();
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                db.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
```

And finally, I'm using a button to call the update method with these codes:

```
 private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(txb_Id.Text);

            Person person = new Person();
            person.ID = id;
            person.Name = txb_Name.Text;
            person.UpdatePerson();

        }
```

Also, I'm using a grid view to show the table

```
private void btn_CG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Database database = new Database();

            string sql = "select * from person";

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable = banco.ExecuteGenericSearch(sql);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

        }
```

Comment: `but I can't find a way to update the records there` you didn't explain your issue you are facing if any?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Side points: you need to dispose your connection, transaction, and command objects with `using` (and then you don't need to mess around with `catch{ tran.Rollback` and `CloseConnection`). You don't need a transaction on a single statement anyway. Should specify `varchar` length, also you can shorten the code `cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Name;` You can use the constructor `new SqlCommand(yourQuery, cn, tran);` And `CommandType.Text` is the default